# Update existing migration with CSV fails

Tags: csv, migration, drupal-8, drush

Import products.csv with `drush migrate:import products` works fine.
The CSV has unique values which are used as key...
When a value needs to be updated in the CSV  when all product nodes are imported, it fails. Was under the assumption that `drush migrate:import products --update` would do this. 
How to update values for an already done import? Is only a roll-back than a possibility?

Answer (score 0):

After running the command drush migrate-status..in UI you have the option update existing content when clicking "List migrations" of products in Migration list page.